# Most elegant way to eliminate equal but opposite data using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I have a relatively simple set of data that looks like this:

```
invoice_id    created_at     amount_in_cents         user_id
  22348       2019-11-07         550                31773927
  22349       2019-11-08        -550                31773927
  22498       2019-11-10        -3400               2389483
  22499       2019-11-10         3400               2389483
  22500       2019-11-11         18000              93842938
```

As you can see, the first two rows of the sample data are attributed to the same user_id, but are of inverse amounts (add up to 0). Same with rows 3 and 4. I want to remove all invoices where there is an inverse invoice for the same user, within 30 days of each other, leaving just the fifth row.

I could do this with python, but it would expand the process a lot. Is there a simple way to do this with SQL?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgres? Please tag only the relevant database.

Comment: Sorry postgres, fixed

Comment: What if you have multiple matches?  For instance, you could have two amounts that are 550.

Comment: this is a great question. If there are two, i'd want to remove a matching set, leaving the extra 550

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `not exists` with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.user_id = t.user_id
        and greatest(t1.created_at, t.created_at) 
            <= least(t1.created_at, t.created_at) + interval '30 days'
        and t1.amount_in_cents = - t.amount_in_cents
)
```

The `not exists` condition ensures that no other record exists for the same user and with an opposite amount within 30 days.

Comment: . . This will not work if there are two charges at 550 and one at -550.  The problem is much harder than it sounds.

Comment: This works for me, if there is two at 550 and one at -550, it removes the 550 and -550, leaving the 550....correct?

Comment: @AshleyO: actually no, Gordon Linoff is correct pointing out that this would not work for this use case - both records 550 record would be eliminated by a unique -550 record if it is within 30 days. You might want to check the other answer too - but it does not handle the 30 days limit. Or maybe give a more detailed description of what you want to implement, with sample data that does represent these edge cases.

Comment: Hmm ok i could just tighten the constraints and put the interval within 2 days. It still works for my specific use case, but that is largely a result of me not perfectly outlining my use case. In your opinions, should I remove the checkmark?

Comment: @AshleyO: you asked the question, and as such you are entirely free to accept or unaccept any answer. But indeed my solution works for your sample data. You might also consider asking a *new question*, with sample data that does cover the edge cases so it is clearer what you expect from the start.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a simple solution to this problem.  If you wanted to remove *all* matching pairs, then you could enumerate and remove:

```
select min(invoice_id), min(created_at), user_id, max(amount_in_cents) as amount_in_cents
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, amount_in_cents order by created_at) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by abs(amount_in_cents), user_id, seqnum
having count(*) = 1;  -- only one "matching" amount
```

However, the limitation on 30 days is challenging and I think you might need a recursive CTE for it.

Consider the following data:

```
1    jan 1     500
1    jan 15    500
1    feb 1     -500
1    feb 10    -500
```

What result would you want?